# case statement to delete extra spaces only when there is some

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, replace, trim

I replace all blanks with @ using this

```
SELECT *,  REPLACE(NAME,' ','@') AS NAME2
```

which results miss@test@blogs@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ (different number of @s dependent on length of name!

I then delete all @ signs after the name using this

```
select *, substring(Name2,0,charindex('@@',Name2)) as name3
```

which then gives my desired results of, for example MISS@test@blogs

However some wheren't giving this result, they are null. This is because annoyingly some rows in the sheet I have read in dont have the spaces after the name.

is there a case statement i can use so it only deletes @ signs after the name if they are there in the first place?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The function `rtrim` can be used to remove trailing spaces.  For example:

```
select replace(rtrim('miss test blogs             '),' ','@')
-->
'miss@test@blogs'
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0cf31/4/0)

Comment: what if there are more than one space between miss and test

Comment: Thanks but that was an example. There are thousands of rows.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Declare @t table (name varchar(100),title varchar(100),forename varchar(100))
insert into @t
values('a  b   c','dasdh  dsalkdk  asdhl','asd dfg sd')


SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(name)),'  ',' '+CHAR(7)),CHAR(7)+' ','')  ,CHAR(7),'') AS Name,

REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(title)),'  ',' '+CHAR(7)),CHAR(7)+' ','')  ,CHAR(7),'') AS title,

REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(forename)),'  ',' '+CHAR(7)),CHAR(7)+' ','')  ,CHAR(7),'') AS forename

FROM @t WHERE
(CHARINDEX('  ',NAME) > 0 or CHARINDEX('  ',title) > 0 or CHARINDEX('  ',forename) > 0)
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6343/1)

Comment: That works but I cant use the rest of my code to seperate the title, forename, surname as the @s are not there. Do you have syntax for that?

Comment: where is the forename being pulled from? Invalid column name 'forename'.

Comment: forename is not in your table?

Comment: no it is stored as a full name field thats why i need to seperate them

Comment: can you pls show me ur table structure i m not getting what exactly u need here

Comment: name is one field that looks like Miss Elle L Pool. They may not have a middle name. I want title forename(and middle if applicable( and surname in all separate fields

Answer (score 2):

```
select name2, left(name2,len(name2)+1-patindex('%[^@]%',reverse(name2)+'.'))
from (
  SELECT *, REPLACE(NAME,' ','@') AS NAME2
  from t
) x;
```

Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1631d/9/2)

For posterity, sample table:

```
create table t (name varchar(100));
insert t select 'name@name@ne@@@'
union all select '@name@name'
union all select 'name name hi   '
union all select 'joe public'
union all select ''
union all select 'joe'
union all select 'joe   '
union all select null
union all select '   leading spaces'
union all select '   leading trailing  ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand the question, but if the problem is there is not spaces after some names, can't you do this first:

```
SELECT *,  REPLACE(NAME+' ',' ','@') AS NAME2
```

i.e., add a space to all names right off the bat?

Comment: thats the problem yes. That still leaves me with some empty fields in name3 (see orginial post)

Answer (score -1):

I had this same problem some days ago.

Well actually, there's a quickly way to subtract the spaces from both the begin and end inside strings. In SQL Server, you can use the RTRIM and LTRIM for this. The first one supresses spaces from right side and the second supresses from left. But, if in your scenario also may exists more than one space in the middle of the string I sugest you take a look on this post on SQL Server Central: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68378/

There the script's author explain, in details, a good solution for this situation.

Comment: You have to sign up for this site?

Comment: Yes. But it's something I sugest, because it's a great resource for SQL Server